# Is there any benefit to lighting the torches in the game?

Tags: dark-souls-2

You are given a torch that you can then use to light your way and also light torch stands spread throughout the world. I have not yet seen any real game benefit to lighting the stands though. I would even say a majority are not really in areas I even really care to light at all. Is there any mechanical benefit to lighting them up?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are four main benefits to using the torch.

- Lighting areas

> The torch can be used to light areas in the game that are dark. In addition you can light the stands as you go through the game so you do not have to travel back to a bonfire or use a Flame Butterfly

- Changing Enemy Reactions

> Certain enemies will react differently if the player has the torch lit and equipped.

- NPC Interactions

> Certain NPC's dialogs will change based on use of the torch. Blacksmith McDuff is found sitting on a chest, if the player uses the torch to light the stand on the other side of the room and reloads at the bonfire, the blacksmith will have moved to the other side and the chest will be free to open.

- Environment Interaction

> Certain boss fights can be made easier with the torch. Using a torch to light certain environmental objects will change both the Lost Sinner and Baneful Queen Mytha fights.

Comment: `you can light the stand as you go through so you don't have to travel back`, you mean you can light torches at the already lit places? or is there some hidden save mechanic of some sort you are referring to?

Comment: @Maslow If you light a stand and unequip your torch you can re-light it at said stand instead of having to run back to the Bonfire. This is especially helpful in No-Man's Wharf.

Answer (score 5):

In early trailers of the game, some areas were completely dark and it was necessary to hold a torch in one hand and your weapon in the other in order to battle enemies in that area. In the end it seems that From Software backed off from that game mechanic but left the torch and sconces in, but as far as I can tell no such areas remain. The sconces would certainly have been very useful in such cases.

Comment: There is a short section in the Forest of Giants where you have to go through a corridor with skeletons. It's behind a door opened with the soldier key. It's quite short, but it's completely dark.

Answer (score 3):

There is at least one NPC whose behavior changes after you light the stationary torch near them.

Comment: Can you add which one in a spoiler?

Comment: @Mondrianaire covers the one one I am thinking of :)

Answer (score 1):

Torches also increase the range you can see and therefore lock on distance.

Answer (score 0):

In Scholar of the First Sin lighting all the torches in Things Betwixt actually does have an effect on the game, and now requires a Fragrant Branch of Yore to accomplish.

Spoily things ahead:

> A Greatsword-armed red phantom will invade you.